# How to process large files?

Tags: parallel-processing, data-processing

I've recently been tasked with designing a service that deals with pre-processing CSVs. The pre-processing involves validation, adding additional columns, and performing transformations. The problem that I'm trying to address now in the service is how I can reduce the pre-processing time. The time required to process the file linearly depends on the size of the file. I'm familiar with the concepts of **multiprocessing** and **multithreading** but, I'm looking to delve further into the topic of processing larger files in general. It would be great if the community could point me to some books or related documentation.

Comment: `awk` will do one file as fast as anything. Multiple `awk` instances under **GNU Parallel** is a very simple and performant way to multiprocess.

Comment: @MarkSetchell wouldn't that require making Unix system calls from the application code. I don't want to do that, I'm looking for an approach that allows me to implement that from within the application code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You better say what language you use then. What's the objection to system calls please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell as I've mentioned I perform some operations on the data inside the CSV and that those operations are specified in the application code and are dependent on libraries that the application uses. The application is written in Python and uses Pandas for handling CSV data. Also as I've mentioned in my post I'm not necessarily looking for a solution specific to my use case but, for strategies that one can implement in such cases, irrespective of the tech stack.

Comment: Please check your question. It doesn't mention application code, libraries, Python, Pandas, strategy, generic or tech stack.

Comment: I think people generally use [Dask](https://dask.org/) to do such kind of operations. While it is not very fast in practice, it is designed to scale on multiple machine with multiple cores and to compute quite big files.